# WordPress with SSL having issues when installing plugins

Tags: ssl, wordpress

I have a WordPress blog set up on a centos 6 vps. I also set up ssl as the default ssl in the apache configuration and everything is working fine. Site is loading without any issues. But if i login to wp admin area, through ssl, then I'm not able to install any plugins, or simply it looks like no write option is working. Any idea what might be causing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution myself. It was a permission issue when the apache is serving via https. I have used webmin to enable ssl I on my site and it is working now.